# how do i send website traffic to an http port if i have Strict-Transport-Security enforced?

Tags: ssl, hsts

how do i send website traffic to an http port
if i have Strict-Transport-Security is enforced

For example 
i have Strict-Transport-Security enforced
if i embed a link that leads to http port 8000
the visitor is directed to https port 8000

The result i needed was
if i embed a link that leads to http port 8000
the visitor is directed to http port 8000

thanks.

Comment: Never mind i found a way to do it. i had to send the website traffic to a php page that header( "Location: http", true, 302);
exit;

Comment: If you somehow resolved this with a "redirect" then it would seem the hostname you are redirecting to is not covered by HSTS (or the original hostname was not covered by HSTS to begin with)? (But this does not appear to prevent the original request still being HTTPS?)

Answer (score 5):

You're misunderstanding the way HSTS (HTTP Strict Transport Security) works. If you enable this header, then client browsers that support HSTS should refuse to make plain HTTP connections to your domain (and potentially all sub-domains) on **any** port.

If a user attempts to connect to http://www.example.com/ (implied port 80) then the browser will automatically change to this https://www.example.com/ (implied port 443)

If the user attempts to connect to http://www.example.com:8000/ (or any port other than 80/443) then the browser will automatically change this to https://www.example.com:8000/ (or whichever port was specified).

If you enable HSTS, then you must be prepared to serve **all** HTTP traffic for your domain over a secure connection.

I don't know what you've done to supposedly work around this, but whether it works or not it's a violation of the HSTS specification and, even if it works now, is likely to stop working in the future.

The correct answer is to properly configure port 8000 to serve traffic over a secure connection.

See the RFC, section 8.3, for further details
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#section-8.3

--

**Edit:** Just an extra point of clarification in case this matters in your scenario;

Note that HSTS doesn't care which server, or IP address you use. Once you start serving the header for a particular domain from **anywhere**, you must serve **all** HTTP traffic to that domain **on any server** over a secure connection.

The flip side to this is that if you have a shared server hosting multiple domains, the domains that aren't serving up the HSTS header can continue to operate over plain HTTP from the same server. HSTS cares about the domain, not the server.

So if the service you have on port 8000 for some reason absolutely can't operate over HTTPS, then another option would be to host it on a different domain, or sub-domain. If you choose to use a sub-domain you need to be sure that the HSTS header has not been set to include sub-domains.

Comment: what i did to make it work doesn't violate of the HSTS specification and, will  still work the future. i found the fix i needed and that's all that matters.